# Is O(log(n)) the correct Big O notation for this function?

Tags: python, big-o

I wrote a function to determine if a given number is a prime number. I have the following code

```
def prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    elif n > 1: 
        for i in range(2, (1+floor(sqrt(n)))):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

I "calculated" the Big O notation to be O(log(n)), but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: How did you calculate?

Comment: I followed a guide I found with breaking down the parts of the code, and I may have missed something, but I found that floor() and sqrt() both were O(1), and that modulo is O(log(n)).

Comment: Whatever guide you are following is wrong about modulo. I've added an answer to breakdown runtime for you for this code. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo, floor and sqrt are all O(1) time. Most basic arithmetic and math operations in Python will have O(1) runtime.

The most relevant thing that will determine your runtime is a loop (or nested loops).

In this case, you have

```
for i in range(sqrt(N))
```

Meaning your program will have to execute everything inside the loop sqrt(N) times. This will give you a runtime of O(sqrt(N)).

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Modulo is not `O(log(n))`, it's just a part of standard integer division and is O(1). You are doing `sqrt(n)` iterations, therefore it's `O(sqrt(n))`. If modulo actually were O(log(n) your result would be `O(sqrt(n)log(n))` not `O(log(n))` since it's repeated sqrt(n) times. Floor is definately O(1), sqrt depends on the implementation but I'm pretty sure it will be O(1) in python.

If you had two sepearate loops: one with `O(sqrt(n))` and another with `O(n^2)` then the whole algo would be `O(n^2)` because `n^2` grows much faster than `sqrt(n)` and you are adding the two together not multiplying them. You multiply when you have a loop inside another loop, if they follow each other you add them and you can't throw away the slower growing part of the multiplication.